# How to add two separate Average line in Tableau

Tags: graph, tableau-api, dashboard

I Have a salary graph. I have added marital status in details so I have married and single Line graph. now I want to add Average line for both.
Currently I have a Average line but it is average of salaries.
I want two separate average line for each married salary and single salary.

Thanks for help.

Comment: did the answer solve your need? if so, please accept the answer in order to mark the thread as closed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your line chart has one point per year, you just need to create a calculated field using LOD in order to calculate the avarages like this one:

```
{ EXCLUDE [year of salary] : AVG ({ FIXED [Marital Status],[year of salary]: SUM([Salary])})}
```

With a dual axis line chart, you can get something like this:
[image]